# Duplex Printing in XML Publisher report (PDF)

Tags: oracle, unix, printing, duplex, oracleapplications

I want to print terms and conditions on Back of odd pages in XML publisher report. I have made the changes in RTF and able to view the output but while printing I'm not getting the prints back to back.
In printer setup inside Oracle Apps Printer-> Drivers I have below given string :

cat $PROFILES$.FILENAME | acroread -toPostScript -shrink | lp -c -d$PROFILES$.PRINTER -n$PROFILES$.CONC_COPIES -t"$PROFILES$.TITLE"

This is printing the output one by one .. need to get this printed in Duplex(Back to Back) mode.

Comment: Which OS?  The duplexing can be set a) in the file, b) in the printer "driver", or c) on the command line of some versions of lp.

Comment: Hi Erik,I have used lp command for printing pdf file from command line as:
cat 32334633.pdf | acroread -toPostScript | lp -dmtr053
the same is not working while using it for duplex printing as :
cat 32334633.pdf | acroread -toPostScript | lp -dmtr053 -o duplex
Please advice..